# run describe schema using datastax cassandra driver 3.0

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

when I am trying to run "describe keyspace keyspacename" command using datastax driver 3.0, it gives me an error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'DESCRIBE' ([DESCRIBE]...)
```

How to run "describe keyspace keyspacename" command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datastax's Java Driver has a class KeyspaceMetadata which exposes the method exportAsString. So I used that method to get entire keyspace schema as string using this method.

Answer (score 7):

`DESCRIBE` is a cqlsh extension.

You could query [system table](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_query_system_c.html) like this

```sql
SELECT * from system.schema_keyspaces 
 WHERE keyspace_name = 'keyspacename';
```

Comment: This method provides only keyspace information, I need schema for column family as well. Sorry, if I was not clear in my question.

Comment: @VarunGupta take a look at the link. There is also `schema_columns` and `schema_columnfamilies` as well. I'll extend my question a bit later.

Comment: hey, update: it should be `keyspace_name = 'keyspacename'`